# CarouFredSel assign dynamic slides

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

Sry for my bad english. I have two tabs. under each tab i want to have a slider. But to ensure performance and dom handling. I just want to have single CarouFredSel object but i want to change the slides and state of pagination elements while changing the tab.

How can i assign slides(collection of divs) to a CarouFredSel slider dynamically, i mean through js?

I dont want to create two CarouFredSel sliders for each tab separately like

```
$("#foo1").carouFredSel();
$("#foo2").carouFredSel();
```

...because the slider pagination(previous/next buttons) are fixed and i dont want to dublicate it for two sliders separately. only i ve to dynamically change the slides to be slide upon changing the tab.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should try giving your sliders the same class and then simply call `$(".slidersclasshere").carouFredSel();`

Comment: this will require two different pagination elements. But what my need is i want to have only one pair of pagination elements(prev/next). want to change the contents to be slide based on tab selection